# Send mail after receive onApprove PayPal

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax, email

i'm trying to send a mail when onApprove is received but i'dont know how to do that. So, this is my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Fede Pistone</title>
    <!-- Internos -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
    <!-- Externos -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3>Formulario de Contacto</h3>
    <div class="container">
      <form method="POST" id="myForm" action="enviarmail.php" >
        <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
        <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" placeholder="Ingresa tu nombre...">
        <label for="apellido">Apellido</label>
        <input type="text" id="apellido" name="apellido" placeholder="Ingresa tu apellido...">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Ingresa tu email...">
        <label for="mensaje">Mensaje:</label>
        <textarea id="mensaje" name="mensaje" placeholder="Ingresa tu consulta..." style="height:200px"></textarea>
        <div id="smart-button-container">
          <div style="text-align: center;">
            <div id="paypal-button-container" name="divPayPal"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <p>Al presionar el botón, se abrirá un formulario en el cuál deberá abonar un monto de u$s20. <br>Recuerde que al presionarlo, usted está aceptando esto. <br>Una vez procesado el pago, recibirá un mail con un link para una reunión virtual con un horario específico. <br>Por favor, consulte en su bandeja de entrada y/o spam.</p>

    <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=sb&enable-funding=venmo&currency=USD" data-sdk-integration-source="button-factory"></script>
    <script>
      function initPayPalButton() {
        paypal.Buttons({
          style: {
            shape: 'rect',
            color: 'gold',
            layout: 'vertical',
            label: 'paypal',

          },

          createOrder: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.order.create({
              purchase_units: [{"description":"Ejemplo de botón","amount":{"currency_code":"USD","value":20}}]
            });
          },

          onApprove: function(data, actions) {
            var nombre = document.getElementById('nombre').value;
            var apellido = document.getElementById('apellido').value;
            var nombreJunto = nombre + " " + apellido;
            var mailForm = document.getElementById('email').value;
            var mensajeForm = document.getElementById('mensaje').value;

            $.ajax({
              url: "enviarmail.php",
              method: "POST",
              data: {action: 'e-mail', nombre: nombreJunto, email: mailForm, mensaje: mensajeForm},
              dataType: "json",
              success: function(response){
                if(response.status == 200){
                  console.log(response + "status: " + response.status);
                  const element = document.getElementById('paypal-button-container');
                  element.innerHTML = '';
                  element.innerHTML = '<h3>Gracias, nos estaremos comunicando contigo a la brevedad.</h3>';
                }else{
                  console.log(response);
                }
              }
            })
          },

          onError: function(err) {
            const element = document.getElementById('paypal-button-container');
            element.innerHTML = '';
            element.innerHTML = '<h3>Ha ocurrido un error, reintente más tarde. </h3>';
            console.log(err);
          }
        }).render('#paypal-button-container');
      }
      initPayPalButton();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And this is my php file to send mails:

```
<?php
    function json_output($status = 200, $msg = 'OK', $data = null){
      header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
      return json_encode([
        'status' => $status,
        'msg' => $msg,
        'data' => $data
      ]);
      die;
     }
    if(isset($_POST["nombre"]) && isset($_POST["email"]) && isset($_POST["mensaje"]) ){
            $to = "francojoelbalsamo@gmail.com";
            $subject = "Datos de formulario de contacto";
            $contenido .= "Nombre: ".$_POST["nombre"]."\n";
            $contenido .= "Apellido: ".$_POST["apellido"]."\n";
            $contenido .= "Email: ".$_POST["email"]."\n\n";
            $contenido .= "Mensaje: ".$_POST["mensaje"]."\n\n";
            $header = "From: francojoelbalsamo@gmail.com\nReply-To:".$_POST["email"]."\n";
            $header .= "Mime-Version: 1.0\n";
            $header .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"UTF-8\"\r\n";
            $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n";
            if(mail($to, $subject, $contenido ,$header)){
                json_output();
            }else{
                json_output();
            }
    }
?>
```

So, here is when i receive `onApprove`:

```
onApprove: function(data, actions)
```

The php file works correctly 'cause i was doing test and works perfectly, now i need send mail after receive onAppove but i'm new in this things i don't know how to do that, so anyone can tell me how i do it?

But, how can i send **mail** when i receive this results?

Well, after read the comments i'm tried with `AJAX function` to send mail but not work correctly 'cause the mail never sends, so this is my new code modified:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "enviarmail.php",
  method: "POST",
  data: {action: 'e-mail', nombre: nombreJunto, email: mailForm, mensaje: mensajeForm},
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(response){
    if(response.status == 200){
      console.log(response + "status: " + response.status);
      const element = document.getElementById('paypal-button-container');
      element.innerHTML = '';
      element.innerHTML = '<h3>Gracias, nos estaremos comunicando contigo a la brevedad.</h3>';
    }
    else{
      console.log(response);
    }
  }
})
```

And my new php file edited:

```
<?php
    function json_output($status = 200, $msg = 'OK', $data = null){
      header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
      return json_encode([
        'status' => $status,
        'msg' => $msg,
        'data' => $data
      ]);
      die;
     }
    if(isset($_POST["nombre"]) && isset($_POST["email"]) && isset($_POST["mensaje"]) ){
            $to = "francojoelbalsamo@gmail.com";
            $subject = "Datos de formulario de contacto";
            $contenido .= "Nombre: ".$_POST["nombre"]."\n";
            $contenido .= "Apellido: ".$_POST["apellido"]."\n";
            $contenido .= "Email: ".$_POST["email"]."\n\n";
            $contenido .= "Mensaje: ".$_POST["mensaje"]."\n\n";
            $header = "From: francojoelbalsamo@gmail.com\nReply-To:".$_POST["email"]."\n";
            $header .= "Mime-Version: 1.0\n";
            $header .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"UTF-8\"\r\n";
            $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n";
            if(mail($to, $subject, $contenido ,$header)){
                json_output();
            }else{
                json_output();
            }
    }
?>
```

can anyone tells me why this not works correctly?

Comment: Use [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) or any other api to post the data from javascript to your server. Way too big of a concept to explain, but go ahead and read about [ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started). You will need this day in day out in web development

Comment: send an AJAX request to the server using fetch() or XHR, or library-of-your-choice

Comment: can you show me a simple example? @ADyson

Comment: There are more than enough Ajax tutorials online to last you a lifetime already, you don't need another one.

Comment: well, i'm use `ajax` after your recomendation but i think that i'm doing something wrong 'cause the mail never sends for any reason. Can you read the new code on the answer and tell me what i'm doing wrong? @marks

Comment: well, i tried it but not works correctly 'cause mail never send. I've added the new code modified, can you tell me my error? thang @ADyson

Comment: "not works" isn't a useful description of the problem. Just because the mail doesn't send doesn't necessarily mean the AJAX failed - a lot else can go wrong in other places. Have you done any debugging to try and narrow down the issue? I will look at the code now and comment further if I notice anything, but issues are not always obvious just by reading.

Comment: The first thing I can see is you're doing `document.getElementById('nombre').value` but in the HTML you have `id="name"`, not `id="nombre"`, so that won't match up and get a value. You might even have a JS error which prevents the code from continuing - have you checked your browser's Console for messages? Same problem with `appelido` vs `lname`, and `mensaje` vs `subject`.

Comment: Also you're not really getting any proper indication of whether `mail()` actually returned true or false, because your code returns exactly the same output in each case! You should vary something in the output so you can see what happens with that.

Comment: `header("Content-Type: aplication/json; charset=utf-8");` contains a typo - it should be `header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8");`

Answer (score 2):

Within the [Set up standard payments guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/set-up-standard-payments/), there are notes in the section of 'Add and modify the code' that explains how to use a server, and link to the necessary resources -- including REST API implementations of create and capture order, and demo code for calling server routes that implement them with `fetch()`.

Sending an email should be done in such a server route, at the time it propagates a successful capture response to the calling JavaScript.